# How to add the values of multidimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, addition

Problem solved thanks guys :

```
foreach($FIMP as &$value){
    foreach($value as &$values){
         $values[0]=$values[3].$values[2].$values[1];
}
```

I have the following arrays:

```
$FIMP=array(
    1 => array(
             1 => array('a','b','c')
             2 => array('a1','b1','c1')
    2 => array(
             1 => array('a2','b2','c2')
    3 => array(
             1 => array('a3','b3','c3')
             2 => array('a4','b4','c4')
             3 => array('a5','b5','c5')
)
```

I want to add the the values: b and c and overwrite a with the 'bc'
result like this

```
$FIMP=array(
    1 => array(
             1 => array('bc','b','c')
             2 => array('b1c1','b1','c1')
    2 => array(
             1 => array('b2c2','b2','c2')
    ...
```

I already tried  $FIMP

```
foreach($FIMP as $value){
    foreach($value as $values){
         $values[0]=$values[3].$values[2].$values[1];
}
```

}

in the out put there is no change to the previous $FIMP ,

Comment: Try passing `$value` as reference: `&$value`

Comment: only three element in array so indexing will not contain $values[3]. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP foreach documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

So to change the values in `$FIMP`, you need to change your foreach loop to the following:

```
foreach($FIMP as &$value){
    foreach($value as &$values){
         // alter $value or $values here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$FIMP=array(
    1 => array(
         1 => array('a','b','c'),
         2 => array('a1','b1','c1'),
    ),
    2 => array(
         1 => array('a2','b2','c2'),
    ),
    3 => array(
         1 => array('a3','b3','c3'),
         2 => array('a4','b4','c4'),
         3 => array('a5','b5','c5'),
    ),
);

foreach($FIMP as & $v1){
    foreach($v1 as & $v2){
        $v2[0] = $v2[1].$v2[2];
    }
}

var_dump($FIMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
  foreach($FIMP as &$first){
       foreach($first as &$second){
            $second[0] = $second[1].$second[2];
       }
  }
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => bc
                [1] => b
                [2] => c
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => b1c1
                [1] => b1
                [2] => c1
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => b2c2
                [1] => b2
                [2] => c2
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => b3c3
                [1] => b3
                [2] => c3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => b4c4
                [1] => b4
                [2] => c4
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => b5c5
                [1] => b5
                [2] => c5
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: $second[0] = $second[1].$second[2];